# How can I use PredicateBuilder with repository pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, predicatebuilder

I am trying to use Joseph Albahari's PredicateBuilder with my applications Respository which is giving me the following error:

**The best overloaded method match for 'MySite.DAL.Respositories.IMyObjRepository.SearchFor(S`ystem.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MySite.DAL.MyObj,bool>>`)' has some invalid arguments**

Signiture for MySite.DAL.Respositories.IMyObjRepository.SearchFor:

```
public IQueryable<MyObj> SearchFor(Expression<Func<MyObj, Boolean>> predicate)
```

Code calling SearchFor:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<MySite.DAL.MyObj>();
predicate = predicate.And(a => a.county.name == CountyName);
return _myObjRespository.SearchFor(predicate);
```

I am aware that I do not need PredicateBuilder for this query - I have simplified it for the purposes of this question. The simplified version still gives the same error.

Any help/ideas/advice appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what type is `CountyName`?

Comment: as it advises [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), did you `remember to call AsExpandable on the first table in the query`?

Comment: CountyName's type is String

Comment: Yes, I am calling AsExpandable - Although this is a compiler error, not run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered the type expected in _myObjRespository.SearchFor() did not match the type I was setting/sending in var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True();

MyObj was replacing my object names for security/confidentiality reasons - I accidently replaced the different types on my original post.